# Combine access to server retrieves data within a playground but not within a function. Why?

Tags: swift, combine

The following code produces the output that I expect:

```
import UIKit
import Combine


    let myURL = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries/Canada")

    // MARK: - Region
    struct Region: Codable {
        let country: String
        let subregions: [String]
    }


    let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: myURL!)
        .map { $0.data }
        .print("Hello Data")
        .decode(type: Region.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

    let cancellableSink = remoteDataPublisher
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print(".sink() received the completion", String(describing: completion))
                switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        break
                    case .failure(let anError):
                        print("received error: ", anError)
                }
        }, receiveValue: { someValue in
            print(".sink() received \(someValue)")
        })


// =====================================================================================================
 
print("The End.")
```

Here's the output as shown in the console. 
As you can see, there is no 'cancel':

[image]

---

However when I wrap the code into a function(), 'combine' CANCELS the output. 
The following code within **getRegionList()** doesn't produce an output.

Instead it receives a 'cancel' as shown in the console following the code below:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

var regionList = [String]()
let simplePublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()


func getRegionList() {
let myURL = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries/Canada")

// MARK: - Region
struct Region: Codable {
    let country: String
    let subregions: [String]
}


let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: myURL!)
    .map { $0.data }
    .print("Hello Data")
    .decode(type: Region.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

    let cancellableSink = remoteDataPublisher
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print(".sink() received the completion", String(describing: completion))
            switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let anError):
                    print("received error: ", anError)
            }
    }, receiveValue: { someValue in
        print(".sink() received \(someValue)")
    })
}
getRegionList()
print("The End.")
```

The function cancels as shown in the console:

[image]

Why?

The only code difference is one *is wrapped in a simple function*.

I suspect some 'lifespan' must have expired.

**Solution:** should I make **concellableSink** global?

 What is the correct solution/syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the `AnyCancellable`, otherwise when it gets freed up, it cancels the subscription, which is what happens when your function returns.

Typically, this is handled by storing the reference in an `AnyCancellable` (or `Set<AnyCancellable>`) property of an instance:

```
class Foo {
   var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

   //...

   func doSomething() {
      somePublisher
        .sink(...)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
   }
}
```

Alternatively, the `sink` closure could keep a reference to its own AnyCancellable, and release it when a value is received, but of course this might be a memory leak if the publisher never publishes anything (though you could mitigate it with a `.timeout` operator):

```
func doSomething() {
   let cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
   cancellable = somePublisher
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
         // ...
         cancellable = nil
      }, receiveValue: { value in
         //...
      })
}
```